# VBA: set gradient fill background angle

Tags: vba, charts, angle

I have the following problem: I want to set a chart background with "Gradient Fill" and change the angle with a macro.

Recording a Macro does not help. The only thing I got is the following:

```
    With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 117, 117)
    .BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 203, 92)
    .TwoColorGradient msoGradientDiagonalUp, 1
End With
```

In reality I want to set the colors in advance and use the macro just for orientation. The only thing the macro should do is:

```
If variable = A then 'select the chart and set angle to 45%
If variable = B then 'select the chart and set the angle to 135%
```

and so on.

I do not want to set manually the colors because I will have 4 colors and it useless to set them every time since their relative position is always the same within the gradient pattern.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made it.

It is very simple, but you cannot easily find this info online.

You need to activate your chart and after:

```
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Format.Fill.GradientAngle = 45
```